# Codeigniter Url issue: HTTP 404

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I am working on codeigniter 
when I used it on xampp server it worked pretty well with this Url
localhost.com/realestate/index.php?class/method/parameter

But when I put similar thing on godaddy host

Same Url segment is showing codeigniter 404 error

Answer (score 2):

Add `.htaccess` for your folder. [Here is some result Check it out all the links.](https://www.google.lk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=godaddy%20htaccess%20codeigniter)

> Host is Case-Sensitive so be careful with naming of Controller and model names as well

Answer (score 1):

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
# RewriteBase /yourfoler/
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|install|update) 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# For godady Shared Hosting Server uncomment the line below
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

# Please comment this if you have uncommented the above
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [NC,L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

`localhost.com/realestate/index.php?class/method/parameter` instead of this you can `localhost.com/realestate/class/method/parameter`run like this with this following htaacess